# "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." С# (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium

Не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка и как ее исправить. Вроде бы конструктор реализовал правильно, а воспользоваться не могу. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

> Сама ошибка: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не
>   указывает на экземпляр объекта."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IWebDriver Browser;
            Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
            Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a1 = textBox1.Text;

            ConstructorTovars CT = new ConstructorTovars(a1);
            CT.FabricateTovars(); 
        }
    }

    class ConstructorTovars{
        public string Link;
        IWebDriver Browser;

        public ConstructorTovars(string Link) {
            this.Link = Link;
        }

        public void FabricateTovars() {
            Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(Link); //ошибка в этой строке
            Browser.FindElement(By.Name("commit")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `связана с переменной Link` - вы уверены? Посмотрите внимательней на `Browser`!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, вы правы, ошибка связанна с Browser, скорее всего ему задается null параметр и в этом и есть корень проблем. Если честно без понятия как это исправить.

Comment: Почитайте ссылку выше и сразу все встанет на свои места. Подсказка - объекты надо инициализировать. Если используем в другом классе, то передаем ссылку на уже инициализированный объект.